# mixing CNTK and Keras codes

Tags: cntk

I know that Keras can be used with CNTK backend.

Question:
In my code can I mix both Keras and CNTK? For example, in my model can I mix up layers (e.g. convolution1d) written in CNTK and Keras?

Answer (score 0):

Nope you can't. Keras implements a wrapper around the backends. You have to wrap your cntk code in the same style as keras.

For objective functions you can write directly in cntk (IIRC)